# Clear pickerview iOS Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, uipickerview

I would like to reset an UIPickerView after selecting a value and pressing a button, (so it doesn't show the previous selection). The problem is I am always getting one of two errors, it changes from run to run with no apparent pattern. Does anyone know what might cause the errors, respectively how to solve the problem? Thanks alot!

Code:

```
NSString * chosen;
NSString * elemString;
NSMutableArray *secondTableArray ;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    secondTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    secondTableView.bounces = YES;
    elemString = @"";
    choosenDocKind = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(pickerViewItems != nil)
    {
        [pickerViewItems release];
        pickerViewItems = nil;
    } 
    if((indexPath.section == 1)&&(indexPath.row == 0))
    {
        NSString * tableString;
        if([temp length] == 0) {
             [secondTableArray removeAllObjects];
             [secondTableView reloadData];  

             // THESE 2 ROWS BELOW CAUSE THE ERRORS
             [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
             [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - button events
- (IBAction)btnSubmitPVSelection:(id)sender
{
    if([choosenPrompt isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"DOCUMENT_REQUEST_LAGER_UM", nil)])
    {
        if(choosenDocKind != nil)
        {
            chosen = choosenDocKind;
            [choosenDocKind release];
            choosenDocKind = nil;
        }
        choosenDocKind = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[pickerViewItems objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]] retain];
    }
    [tvArchDocParam reloadData];
    if(choosenPrompt != nil)
    {
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [choosenPrompt release];
        choosenPrompt = nil;
    }
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Errors:

```
1. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
2. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason NSDictionaryM reloadAllComponents
```

Comment: is pickerView a property ?

Comment: it looks like for some reason your pickerView variable is not pointing at your picker view anymore, instead it's pointing at an NSMutableDictionary. I would try putting a breakpoint just above the line that crashes and trying to po the value of 'pickerView' in the debugger, if sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't then my guess is that at some point your reference to the picker view is dropping, and that's when you see the crash.

Comment: @enzo No, it is simply declared as an: "UIPickerView *pickerView" in the .h file